# apt-get upgrade complains about authentication of packages

Tags: server, apt, upgrade

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04.1 server.

When issuing a:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

apt-get says:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated
```

This is a fresh install from an ISO that used to deploy 6 other VMs with. The only thing I am seeing is this VM because it is in a different location is pointing to a different server for updates.

I have tried reinstalling the VM 3 times. I have rebuilt the /var/lib/apt/lists directory. I have also tried updating the keys using:

```
sudo apt-key update
sudo apt-key net-update
sudo aptitiude reinstall ubuntu-keyring
```

The packages that it is trying to update are:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice apport byobu gir1.2-glib-2.0 krb5-locales
  libaccountsservice0 libc-bin libc6 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgssapi-krb5-2
  libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libpam-systemd libssl1.0.0
  libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-login0 libudev1 multiarch-support net-tools
  openssl python3-apport python3-distupgrade python3-gi python3-problem-report
  screen systemd-services ubuntu-release-upgrader-core udev
```

After I click "y" this is what I get:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libc-bin libc6 libssl1.0.0 udev libudev1 libk5crypto3 libgssapi-krb5-2
  libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libpam-systemd systemd-services libsystemd-daemon0
  libsystemd-login0 multiarch-support net-tools accountsservice
  libaccountsservice0 libgirepository-1.0-1 gir1.2-glib-2.0 krb5-locales
  openssl ubuntu-release-upgrader-core python3-distupgrade python3-gi
  python3-problem-report python3-apport apport screen byobu
Install these packages without verification? [y/N]
```

I am concerned that I am downloading compromised packages. Also apt-get update runs fine without any warnings.

Comment: What packages are listed?

Comment: Added packages list

Comment: Does it list any key fingerprints?

Comment: Pasted the output from apt-get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be a proxy configured on our Firewall. I am working with our IT department to figure out what setting it is exactly but what was happening is when apt-get would make a call to */Release.gpg and the content-type was set to "text/html" the proxy would deny the request.

I wish apt-get update would indicate issues when downloading the files as this would of saved a lot of time.