# 16.04 Gimp packages cannot be authenticated

Tags: apt, gimp

I'm trying to install the most stable, boring version of GIMP available, without adding special repositories. I'm assuming the correct way to do this is `sudo apt install gimp`. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following warning:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libbabl-0.1-0 libsdl1.2debian libamd2.4.1 libcamd2.4.1 libccolamd2.9.1
  libcholmod3.0.6 libumfpack5.7.1 libgegl-0.3-0
```

Should this be happening? I tried running

```
sudo apt-key update
sudo apt-get update
```

which didn't fix the issue. What should I do?

Edit: Here is the full output of `sudo apt install gimp`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libmircommon5 linux-headers-4.4.0-78 linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-79 linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-79-generic
  linux-tools-4.4.0-78 linux-tools-4.4.0-78-generic linux-tools-4.4.0-79
  linux-tools-4.4.0-79-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gimp-data libamd2.4.1 libbabl-0.1-0 libcamd2.4.1 libccolamd2.9.1
  libcholmod3.0.6 libgegl-0.3-0 libgimp2.0 libsdl1.2debian libumfpack5.7.1
Suggested packages:
  gimp-help-en | gimp-help gimp-data-extras
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gimp gimp-data libamd2.4.1 libbabl-0.1-0 libcamd2.4.1 libccolamd2.9.1
  libcholmod3.0.6 libgegl-0.3-0 libgimp2.0 libsdl1.2debian libumfpack5.7.1
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 79.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libbabl-0.1-0 libsdl1.2debian libamd2.4.1 libcamd2.4.1 libccolamd2.9.1
  libcholmod3.0.6 libumfpack5.7.1 libgegl-0.3-0
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] n
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
```

EDIT: I don't believe this question is a duplicate of any of the questions suggested by reviewers:

- [Why am I getting authentication errors for packages from an Ubuntu repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75565/why-am-i-getting-authentication-errors-for-packages-from-an-ubuntu-repository) None of the answers are the one that worked for me.
- [W: GPG error and WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677939/w-gpg-error-and-warning-the-following-packages-cannot-be-authenticated) Does not have the answer that worked for me.
- [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) This is not the error I got initially.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I'm not getting any "GPG" errors.

Comment: Perhaps [https://askubuntu.com/questions/75565/why-am-i-getting-authentication-errors-for-packages-from-an-ubuntu-repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75565/why-am-i-getting-authentication-errors-for-packages-from-an-ubuntu-repository) or [https://askubuntu.com/questions/516378/apt-get-upgrade-complains-about-authentication-of-packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516378/apt-get-upgrade-complains-about-authentication-of-packages)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I don't think so - The top two answers to that question didn't solve my problem (I tried them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a bunch of things, but ultimately what fixed it was:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
```

From: [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)